# Debian - problems updating mysql 5.6

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

I just tried to update my dev database that runs on debian 7.8. Unfortunately it's now giving me the folllowing error:

```
...
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'utilities-1.4/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` file is as such:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy mysql-5.6
# deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy connector-python-2.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy utilities-1.4

deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy mysql-5.6
```

Has anyone got some tips how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem isn't with Debian, it's with the repository that MySQL are offering. The `Release` file only mentions `utilities-1.5` wheras you have `utilities-1.4` listed in your `mysql.list`. So you probably need to do `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config` as shown in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Full credit to @wurtel for giving me the answer in the comments.

The solution is to run `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config` which brings up a menu. Select utilities, then ok as shown below.

[image]

Then select mysql-utilities-x, then ok.

[image]

Then on the next menu. Select Apply.

[image]

Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything works.